# Access VBA decode

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA code, and working on a project to revised a built MS Access database that has some VBA code built from another person. Can some one explain what the code below would do? My end goal to to create a Data Entry form that would keep previous value from some fields when the users enter the next New Record. Thank you so much.

```
'Private Sub DocumentTypeCombo1_AfterUpdate()
'Me.DocumentNameCombo1 = Null
'Me.DocumentNameCombo1.Requery
'Me.OrderBy = "Errors DESC"
'Me.DocumentNameCombo1 = Me.DocumentNameCombo1.ItemData(0)
'End Sub

'Private Sub DocumentNameCombo1_AfterUpdate()
'Me.SubcategoryCombo1 = Null
'Me.SubcategoryCombo1.Requery
'Me.OrderBy = "SubCategory DESC"
'Me.SubcategoryCombo1 = Me.SubcategoryCombo1.ItemData(0)
'Me.DocumentNameCombo1.Tag = Me.DocumentNameCombo1
'End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the help center and read about what constitutes a good question. As it stands now, this question of "what does this code do?" Is not a good question because it's too broad.

Comment: However, if you just copied-pasted the code exactly how it is, the decoding is very easy: it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: The entire code block is a comment, it does nothing and has no effect on your program logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is commented out, so it does nothing. Even if not, it wouldn't as it misses this line:

```
Me.OrderBy = "Errors DESC"
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

If you include the line, it will rearrange the sorting of Me.

To ...

> keep previous value from some fields when the users enter the next New Record

you would set the DefaultValue (always a string value) in the AfterUpdate event:

```
Me!SomeControl.DefaultValue = Chr(34) & Me!SomeControl.Value & Chr(34)
```